# Replacement for JSON_ARRAYAGG and JSON_OBJECT from MySQL in v5.6 or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.6

I've inherited an old project that runs on MySql 5.6 and Zend FW 2. I'm trying to run a query that will give the same results as JSON_OBJECT() but mysql 5.6 doesn't support that.

Basically I have 2 tables

Receipts -

| receipt_id | phone | amount | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7777777777 | 5682 | Success |
| 2 | 8888888888 | 4586 | Success |
| 3 | 5555555555 | 7589 | Success |

Receipt_Item -

| receipt_id | item_id | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23 | 5682 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 | 5682 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | 7589 |
| 3 | 1 | 23 | 4355 |
| 3 | 2 | 41 | 3665 |

And need to get this output

```
[
    {
        "receipt_id": 1,
        "phone": "7777777777",
        "amount": "5682",
        "status": "Success",
        "receipt_item" : [
            {
              "receipt_id" : 1,
              "item_id" : 1,
              "quantity" : 23,
              "price" : 5682
            },
            {
              "receipt_id" : 1,
              "item_id" : 2,
              "quantity" : 30,
              "price" : 5682
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "receipt_id": 2,
        "phone": "8888888888",
        "amount": "4586",
        "status": "Success",
        "receipt_item" : [
            {
              "receipt_id" : 2,
              "item_id" : 1,
              "quantity" : 10,
              "price" : 7589
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "receipt_id": 3,
        "phone": "5555555555",
        "amount": "7589",
        "status": "Success",
        "receipt_item" : [
            {
              "receipt_id" : 3,
              "item_id" : 1,
              "quantity" : 23,
              "price" : 4355
            },
            {
              "receipt_id" : 3,
              "item_id" : 2,
              "quantity" : 41,
              "price" : 3665
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

Due to the version I cannot use JSON_OBJECT(). Is there any other way in sql to get this result.

If not can I post-process this in PHP to combine multiple objects with the same receipt_id and creating an inner array with combined receipt items?

Essentially turning this:

```
[
    [
        "receipt_id"    => 1,
        "phone"     => "7777777777",
        "amount"    => "5682",
        "status"    => "Success",
        "item_id"     => 1,
        "quantity"      => 23,
        "price"     => 5682
    ],
    [
        "receipt_id"    => 1,
        "phone"     => "7777777777",
        "amount"    => "5682",
        "status"    => "Success",
        "item_id"     => 1,
        "quantity"      => 23,
        "price"     => 5682
    ],
]
```

into this

```
[
    [
        "receipt_id"    => 1,
        "phone"    => "7777777777",
        "amount"    => "5682",
        "status"    => "Success",
        "receipt_item"     => [
            [
              "item_id"     => 1,
              "quantity"     => 23,
              "price"     => 5682
            ],
            [
              "item_id"     => 2,
              "quantity"     => 30,
              "price"     => 5682
            ]

        ]
    ],
]
```

In PHP I can use `array_unique()` and `array_column()`, and then loop through the original array to get the result. But is there an in-built way to get there?

Thanks.

Comment: On 5.6 you may use string processing functions (CONCAT, GROUP_CONCAT) only. If you'll be accurate then you'll achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate data on PHP side using `array_reduce`:

```
$output = array_reduce(
    $input,
    function($acc, $r) {
        if (!isset($acc[$r["receipt_id"]])) {
            $acc[$r["receipt_id"]] =  [
                "receipt_id"    => $r["receipt_id"],
                "phone"         => $r["phone"],
                "amount"        => $r["amount"],
                "status"        => $r["status"],
                "receipt_item"  => []
            ];
        }
        
        $acc[$r["receipt_id"]]["receipt_item"][] = [
            "item_id"  => $r["item_id"],
            "quantity" => $r["quantity"],
            "price"    => $r["price"]
        ];
        return $acc;
    },
    []
);
```

[run PHP online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php7/f2e363c9e3cfbb82764f8ba987f2d53d/)